# How do I obtain the debian-installer for Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, debian-installer

Where can I find the debian-installer iso cd for Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS?

Comment: What do you mean by debian-installer? You can find Ubuntu iso at ubuntu.com.

Comment: Please check here: https://ubuntu.com/download/server

Comment: @Pilot6 debian-installer is the name one of the installers that some Ubuntu ISO images use. The other major installers used in official Ubuntu media are curtin and, of course, Ubiquity.

Comment: @chili555 Those are the live server installer ISOs, which use [curtin](https://launchpad.net/curtin) rather than debian-installer.

Comment: @EliahKagan And what is the reason to need debian-installer?

Comment: @Pilot6 Some people may prefer it. It probably works better than curtin on a few systems and for some kinds of installations. It also offers different selections (via tasksel). I've found the resulting systems with debian-installer and curtin are a bit different. Anyway, debian-installer is still supported in Ubuntu, and there are official ISO images that provide it, including for 18.04.3 LTS. (I'm writing an answer.)

Answer (score 13):

Ubuntu Server ISO images with debian-installer continue to be available, including for 18.04.3 LTS. There is no need to use media for an earlier point release. **You most likely want [`ubuntu-18.04.3-server-amd64.iso`](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.3/release/ubuntu-18.04.3-server-amd64.iso)**, though [other architectures are available](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.3/release/).

On the [main download page](https://ubuntu.com/#download), the [Use the traditional installer](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer) link takes you to a section for the "Alternative Ubuntu Server installer." These are the non-live ISO images for Ubuntu Server that use debian-installer (as Ubuntu Server has used exclusively for most of its history). This is in contrast to the more recently introduced *live server* images, which use [curtin](https://launchpad.net/curtin).

The link there for 18.04.3 LTS takes you to **http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.3/release/**. The alternative server ISOs have names like `ubuntu-18.04.3-server-arm64.iso`; this indicates they use debian-installer. This is in contrast to the server ISOs offered at http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.3/, which have names like `ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso` and use curtin.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.3/release/ has other architectures, .torrent and .jigdo files (including for the alternative server ISO), the preinstalled images, and manifest and checksum files for everything offered there.

Comment: +1. I tried to answer this question, but failed. This is a good answer. I will try to remember how to find these links, so I mark this question as a favourite.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks! There's another way to find the links that I didn't cover here, having to do with the different roles served by the the releases, cdimage, and old-releases servers. This relates to why you were able to find an older point release on the old-releases server: images from both the releases and cdimage servers are eventually moved there. It would probably be good for *some* answer to cover that, and yours relates to it; I don't know if you feel it would be appropriate to edit your post so it answers the question from that angle (and undelete it), but I think that could be helpful.

Comment: I think it is better to create a [new question and answer from that other angle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186400/how-can-i-find-all-ubuntu-iso-files-and-other-images/1186404#1186404), that you describe. So as a consequence I think it is best to delete my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for Ubuntu 18.04.3 server edition. I hope the official Ubuntu links will help you:

1. https://ubuntu.com/download/server
2. https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer- Alternate Downloads!