# How can I find all Ubuntu iso files and other images?

Tags: iso, disk-image

I think the standard web site for Ubuntu iso files is

https://ubuntu.com/download

But it is difficult to find some of the files that way. Please describe how to find all Ubuntu iso files and other images! Are there any shortcuts or web sites that are possible to remember?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ or https://releases.ubuntu.com/ . For older releases: https://old-releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: @Kulfy, Yes, these are the websites that I want to focus on :-) Let us hope that there will be even more websites and/or details, that can help people find the Ubuntu version and flavour that they are looking for :-)

Comment: http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ : "Official Ubuntu images and are pre-installed disk images that have been customized by Ubuntu engineering to run on public clouds that provide Ubuntu Certified Images, Openstack, LXD, and more."

Comment: @user535733, That's right :-) Do you want to make an own answer about `cloud-images`, or do you want me to make a paragraph about it in my answer?

Comment: @sudodus your answer is already great, so I leave the addition to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Three Ubuntu web sites that you can remember

Please look at the three following links,

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com

http://releases.ubuntu.com/

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

### `cdimage`

A lot of official Ubuntu files, including the daily iso files of the developing version as well as released server files, are found at the `cdimage` web site. Here we focus on

#### Ubuntu Server

- **`server` iso files with the traditional debian installer** and
- compressed image files of preinstalled server systems

Such files for many different architectures are found at the sub-directory

**http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.3/release/**

This link will be modified and point to a new version, when 18.04.3 is no longer the newest LTS [point] release. It should be easy to find the corresponding sub-directory of `cdimage` (as long as the current structure will be maintained).

#### Ubuntu netboot alias `mini.iso`

It is worth pointing to the following link,

**http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/**

where we can find the Ubuntu **`mini.iso`** files, which are extremely small, and also have the debian installer. If you are happy with installing your server or desktop system in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), you can start from an Ubuntu `mini.iso` file.

There are still 32-bit `mini.iso` files (for previous versions and including a current version 18.04 LTS) for really old computers.

### `releases`

The desktop iso files, community family flavours (also with desktop environments) and the new style 'live-server' iso files with the `curtin` installer are found at

http://releases.ubuntu.com/

### `old-releases`

The files at those two web sites will be moved to

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

when it is time to replace them with newer versions. Here I found a corresponding server iso file with the debian installer for version 18.04.1 LTS, with a long time left until [end of life](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle). This version will stay with the hardware enablement stack around the linux kernel series 4.15.

---

*You can find a lot of versions and flavours of Ubuntu via these three links. It is a good idea to browse them (spend some time to climb down into the directory trees).*

---

### `cloud-images`

There is also an Ubuntu web site,

http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/

with customized images to be used on public clouds:

> Ubuntu Cloud Images are the official Ubuntu images and are
> pre-installed disk images that have been customized by Ubuntu
> engineering to run on public clouds that provide Ubuntu Certified
> Images, Openstack, LXD, and more.

### Screenshots

The following screenshots can help you see what you can expect to find via these three websites,

#### cdimage.ubuntu.com:

[image: cdimage]

---

#### releases.ubuntu.com:

[image: releases]

---

#### old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases (sorted by last modified):

[image: old-releases/.../releases]